# format output of json encode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have used ajax, php and json to retrieve information from mysql database.

My code is as shown.

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; //replace with your hostname 
$username = "Practical4"; //replace with your username 
$password = "1234"; //replace with your password 
$db_name = "Practical4"; //replace with your database

$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "select * from comment where name='$name'"; //replace emp_info with your table name 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();

if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $json['comment'][] = $row;
    }
}

mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 

?>
```

The code works and output like this:

```
{"comment":[["42","this is comment one","National Hotel"],["43","this is comment one","National Hotel"],["44","this is comment two","National Hotel"],["45","this is comment two","National Hotel"]]}
```

I'd like to reformat the result to only display content of each comment line by line, like:

```
this is comment one
this is comment two
```

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Wait..where should the reformatting be done? in the php page or in the page which sent the ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then instead of doing json_encode, it would be good if you directly echoed your comment line or captured all the comments line only in an array and perform implode of that array as below

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; //replace with your hostname 
$username="Practical4"; //replace with your username 
$password="1234"; //replace with your password 
$db_name="Practical4"; //replace with your database 
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from comment where name='$name'"; //replace emp_info with your table name 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        //$json['comment'][]=$row;
        echo $row[1];
    }
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

OR

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; //replace with your hostname 
$username="Practical4"; //replace with your username 
$password="1234"; //replace with your password 
$db_name="Practical4"; //replace with your database 
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from comment where name='$name'"; //replace emp_info with your table name 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        //$json['comment'][]=$row;
        $json[] = $row[1];
    }
}
mysql_close($con);
echo implode('<br />', $json);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't have `dataType` mentioned in your ajax call

```
success:function(data)
{
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        var response;
        $.each(data.comment, function(index, value){
             response += value+'<br />';
        });
        $('#your_div_id').html(response);
}
```

If you did have `dataType='json'` specified

```
success:function(data)
{                 
        var response;
        $.each(data.comment, function(index, value){
             response += value+'<br />';
        });
        $('#your_div_id').html(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
foreach($json['comment'] as $key=>$arr)
{
   echo $arr[1]."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to do the formatting?

In PHP for example (why the JSON encoding?)

```
foreach(json_decode($json)->comment as $item)
{
    echo $item[1] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the column if it is your require data column or not, store only your required data with a key => value pair mapping like this:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; //replace with your hostname 
$username="Practical4"; //replace with your username 
$password="1234"; //replace with your password 
$db_name="Practical4"; //replace with your database 
$con=mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql = "select * from comment where name='$name'"; //replace emp_info with your table name 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
 while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)){
   if(column_no == 2)        // Check the column only for demo 
   $json['comment']['message']=$row;
 }
}
mysql_close($con);
echo json_encode($json); 

?>
```

When you get the ajax response your JS code will be ( here data is your response value ):

```
    $.each(data.comment, function(index, value){
         console.log(value.message)
    });
```